# Kendo Vue Treelist duplicate a template when expanding/collapsing item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I'm using Kendo Vue's TreeList component, the problem comes when I use a Vue Template on the TreeList column and later expand or collapse the element.

The initial status of component:
[image]

The result when expanding the element:
[image]

The result when collapsing the element:
[image]

As you can see, every time I expand / collapse an element, the 'acciones' column template is redrawn, so on until I have many instances.

**Parent component:**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <treelistdatasource ref="remoteDataSource" :data="estructurasEvaluacion" :schema-model="model"/>

        <treelist data-source-ref="remoteDataSource">
            <treelist-column field="nombre"
                             title="Evaluación"
                             :width="250"
                             :expandable="true"/>
            <treelist-column field="nombreCorto" title="Nombre corto"/>
            <treelist-column field="porcentaje" title="Porcentaje (%)" :template="porcentajeTemplate"/>
            <treelist-column title="Cálculo de nota" :template="calculoNotaTemplate"/>
            <treelist-column title="Acciones" :template="accionesTemplate" :width="80"/>
        </treelist>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
methods: {
    accionesTemplate (e) {
        return {
            template: Vue.component('acciones', Acciones),
            templateArgs: Object.assign({}, e, {
                parentComponent: this.$refs.tl
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Template component:**

```js
<template>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" title="Editar" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button type="button" title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                templateArgs: {}
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

I'm using Kendo UI 2020.3.1118 and Vue 2.5.17.

```json
"devDependencies": {
        "@progress/kendo-datasource-vue-wrapper": "^2020.3.1118",
        "@progress/kendo-dropdowns-vue-wrapper": "^2020.3.1118",
        "@progress/kendo-grid-vue-wrapper": "^2020.3.1118",
        "@progress/kendo-inputs-vue-wrapper": "^2020.3.1118",
        "@progress/kendo-layout-vue-wrapper": "^2020.3.1118",
        "@progress/kendo-popups-vue-wrapper": "^2020.3.1118",
        "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.25.2",
        "@progress/kendo-treelist-vue-wrapper": "^2020.3.1118",
        "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2020.3.1118",
        "@progress/kendo-window-vue-wrapper": "^2020.3.1118",
        ...
}
```

Comment: which version of kendo are u using?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it..  
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ac2w7q?file=src/acciones.vue 

If still problem persist, host ur code in stackbiltz

Comment: @VireshMathad I'm using '2020.3.1118' version

Comment: @VireshMathad I put the source code in StackBlitz (the same link)... it doesn't work

Comment: could u share the link pls . Link will be different for every fork.

Comment: @VireshMathad yep, https://vue-vd7dw2.stackblitz.io ... 
there is a rendering error, that probably causes the bug

Comment: @VireshMathad  I could not reproduce the error in its entirety, the only difference between this (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ac2w7q-uxbrcr?file=src/main.vue) and my machine is the version of Vue (I use 2.6 vs version 3 of StackBlitz)

Comment: or may be u are using Vue.component('acciones', Acciones) ? instead, u could just import it. Have u tried it?

Comment: Any result on this issue? Experiencing the same thing...